# Difficulty getting functions to work in my Javascript class

Tags: javascript

**Clearly, a new developer! Thank you for replying in advance, I know the answer must be really simple but I have been stuck for an hour.**

This exercise asks to create a class and then asks to change some of the dynamic values using class methods/functions. I am not able to get my values to change when I call the function.

Here are the directions for the exercise, followed by my code, sorry that my work looks so rudimentary!

***These are the directions: 

// Create a new class called SuperHero 

// - Your class should have the following DYNAMIC values 

//   - name 

//   - superpower 

//   - age 

// - Your class should have the following STATIC values 

//   - archNemesis, assigned to "The Syntax Error" 

//   - powerLevel = 100 

//   - energyLevel = 50 

//Where I start having issues is here: 

// - Create the following class methods 

//   - sayName, should print the hero's name to the console 

//   - maximizeEnergy, should update the energyLevel to 1000 

//   - gainPower, should take an argument of a number and INCREASE the powerLevel
  //by that number***

```
    class SuperHero {
      constructor(name, superpower, age,){
        this.name = name;
        this.superpower = superpower;
        this.age = age;
        this.archNemesis = "The Syntax Error";
        this.powerLevel = 100;
        this.energyLevel = 50;
      }
    
    var power = 20;
    
      sayName() {
        console.log(this.name);
      }
    
      maximizeEnergy() {
        this.energyLevel = 1000;
      }
    
    
    gainPower(power) {
        this.powerLevel = this.powerLevel + power;
      }
    };
    
    var superHero1 = new SuperHero("Batman", "strength", 40);
```

Thanks again! :)

Comment: `this.energyLevel` is a `Number` - so `this.energyLevel(1000);` won't work, since it's not a `Function` ... `this.energyLevel =1000;` - you'll probably figure out rest yourself now - except how you define `gainPower` - that will show as an error, did you check the console for errors?

Comment: also, why are `archNemesis, powerLevel, energyLevel` arguments to `constructor` if they're NOT used (and shouldn't be there anyway according to the homework qiestion)

Comment: Pro tip: Sentences clarifying that you are a new dev and "please help" or "thanks" are not really useful and not necessary in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you code is 80% correct. Only issues I see is the `this.energyLevel(1000);` and `sayName()` method. They are not really required.

`this.energyLevel` is a property and not a function, so calling it like `this.energyLevel(1000);` is wrong. You should be setting this value as `this.energyLevel = 1000;`

`sayName()` is not really doing anything useful. You are already setting/initializing the name in the constructor.

Here is a simple example of a class and how to use it's `methods` for changing it's `property` values. Check the output in your browser `console`.

```js
class SuperHero {
  constructor(name, superpower, age, archNemesis, powerLevel, energyLevel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.superpower = superpower;
    this.age = age;
    this.archNemesis = "The Syntax Error";
    this.powerLevel = 100;
    this.energyLevel = 50;
  }

  maximizeEnergy() {
    this.energyLevel = 1000;
  }

  gainPower(gainPower = 20) {
    this.powerLevel += gainPower;
  }
  
}

var superHero1 = new SuperHero("Batman", "strength", 40, "The Joker", 100, 50);
var superHero2 = new SuperHero("Wonder Woman", "agility", "Cheetah", 1000, 1000);

console.log('name', superHero1.name);
console.log('superpower',superHero1.superpower);
console.log('archNemesis',superHero1.archNemesis);
console.log('energyLevel',superHero1.energyLevel);
superHero1.gainPower(100);
console.log('powerLevel',superHero1.powerLevel);
console.log('-------------------------------------');
console.log('name', superHero2.name);
console.log('superpower',superHero2.superpower);
console.log('archNemesis',superHero2.archNemesis);
console.log('energyLevel',superHero2.energyLevel);
superHero2.gainPower(200);
console.log('powerLevel',superHero2.powerLevel);
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to do things more like this:

```
sayName() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

maximizeEnergy() {
  this.energyLevel = 1000;
}

gainPower(power) {
  this.powerLevel = this.powerLevel + power;
}
```

They are all pretty self explanatory.

Comment: OP wants to create a function called `sayName` that prints the answer on the console

Comment: thank you! I edited my original code. Do I need to declare the variable `power` inside or outside of the Class? Thanks and I apologize for being so green!

Comment: power is self declared as an argument of that function. nothing more is needed.